# How to update a value inside an object which is inside array of another object in mongodb using python code

Tags: python, mongodb

My collection looks like this

```
 {"ingr": [
{
  "ingrName": [
    {
      "_id": "57aa56e2a06b57b",
      "name": "abc",
      "type": "ingr"
    }
  ],
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62232cd70ce38c50"
  },
  "quantity": "1.0",
  
},
{
  "ingr": [
    {
      "_id": "607e7fcca57aa",
      "name": "xyz",
      "type": "ingr"
    }
  ],
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62232cd70ce38c"
  },
  "quantity": "1.0"
}
}}
```

I just want to change the id and type based on the object id. what i tried is

```
db1.update_one({
              'ingr.$._id': ObjectId("62232cd70ce38c50")
             
},

{
  '$set': {
  "ingr.ingrName.$.type":"alternate",
    "ingr.ingrName.$._id":"abc123"
            }
})
```

But the values are not changing.Help me to find the mistake I making. Thanks

expected output

```
         {"ingr": [
{
  "ingrName": [
    {
      "_id": "abc123",
      "name": "abc",
      "type": "alternate"
    }
  ],
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62232cd70ce38c50"
  },
  "quantity": "1.0",
  
}
```

i need to change the id and type

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you provide an expected result?

Comment: update the id and type inside ingrName

Comment: Please update the documents as well. They are not valid objects...

Comment: What happens if there is more than one item on the `ingrName` array? Do you want to update all of them? Do you assume there is always only one item there?

Comment: there are multiple items, each having an objectId. I need to update only few based on this object id

Comment: You provided the `_id` of the item on `inger` not on `ingerName`...Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AhgUWZKIumz) an option to a document on your collection? a document which have multiple items on  **ingerName**?